# How to remove folder from url string in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to construct a query in MYSQL that will remove a date folder from an image url string.

The urls are in specific field in the database which relates to the post text of a forum, and as such there is other text in the same field.

A typical url looks like:

```
https://images.mywebsite.com/20170215/ab3c2d9b9a9e6364a07573715d29232d.jpg
```

In the above example I'm trying to remove 20170215 which is the date when the image was uploaded. Basically so that it looks like:

```
https://images.mywebsite.com/ab3c2d9b9a9e6364a07573715d29232d.jpg
```

Obviously there are multiple folders with different dates (folder names).

The image name is variable and always 32 characters long (plus the .jpg ext).

The date folder name is variable and is always 8 characters long.

table is called "messages"
column is called "body"

url is in body along with other general text.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show the structure of your table containing the images?

Comment: What have you tried? What reference pages did you read? This is not a "code it for me" service.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for your case:

```
select concat_ws('/',
                 substring_index(url, '/', 4),
                 substring_index(url, '/', -1)
                )
```

This will not work if the folders are nested.

An alternative method depends on the length of the strings:

```
select concat(left(substr(url, length(url, -45)),
              substring_index(url, '/', -1)
             )
```

Comment: As this is a forum there are potentially other urls in the same field that need to remain unchanged, consequently would this work with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Mysql [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function. Just Update link with new link